# Contact us email php error

Tags: php, contact-form

I am trying to make a contact form and am getting this generic error:

```
    Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

I cannot figure out how to get it to actually log or echo the error. This is my php file:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_log', 'php.log');
$field_fname = $_GET['fname'] ;
$field_lname = $_GET['lname'] ;
$field_bname = $_GET['bname'] ;
$field_email = $_GET['email'] ;
$field_address = $_GET['address'] ;
$field_city = $_GET['city'] ;
$field_state = $_GET['state'] ;
$field_zip = $_GET['zip'] ;
$field_country = $_GET['country'] ;
$field_comments = $_GET['comments'] ;

$mail_to = 'myemail@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_fname .$field_lname;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_fname .$field_lname 'at' .$field_bname "\n";
$body_message = 'E-mail: '.$field_email "\n";
$body_message = 'Address:'.$field_address "\n";
$body_message = 'City:'.$field_city "\n";
$body_message = 'State:'.$field_state "\n";
$body_message = 'Zip Code:'.$field_zip "\n";
$body_message = 'Country:'.$field_country "\n";
$body_message = 'Message: '.$field_comments;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to myemail@mydomain.com');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I am not sure what I am doing is wrong. If someone could either help me find the error or direct me to logging or echoing the error I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: What version of PHP? Prior to 5.4, you should do `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)`. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You also missed another period on line 20, one on 21, one on 22, one on 23, one on 24, one on 25, and one on 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a heap of concatenators(`.`) when building your `$body_message`.

```
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_fname .$field_lname.'at' .$field_bname."\n";
$body_message = 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
```

and so on.

Any decent editor will flag this as an error before you even save the file.

Answer (score 1):

I put your code in a file called so.php
and it has a parse error line 20

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in so.php on line 20`

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in so.php on line 20`

`Errors parsing so.php`

You missed a concatenating dot on line 20 after `$field_lname` and before `'at'`

You might be interested in making a local install of php on your system (wamp for example of easy one) then put the php executable in your path so you can run command line `php -l filename.php` to get instant parse error messages like the one above.

Here is your code with all the parse errors fixed:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_log', 'php.log');
$field_fname = $_GET['fname'] ;
$field_lname = $_GET['lname'] ;
$field_bname = $_GET['bname'] ;
$field_email = $_GET['email'] ;
$field_address = $_GET['address'] ;
$field_city = $_GET['city'] ;
$field_state = $_GET['state'] ;
$field_zip = $_GET['zip'] ;
$field_country = $_GET['country'] ;
$field_comments = $_GET['comments'] ;

$mail_to = 'myemail@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_fname .$field_lname;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_fname .$field_lname .'at' .$field_bname ."\n";
$body_message = 'E-mail: '.$field_email ."\n";
$body_message = 'Address:'.$field_address ."\n";
$body_message = 'City:'.$field_city ."\n";
$body_message = 'State:'.$field_state ."\n";
$body_message = 'Zip Code:'.$field_zip ."\n";
$body_message = 'Country:'.$field_country ."\n";
$body_message = 'Message: '.$field_comments;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to myemail@mydomain.com');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you I see that now and have fixed it. I am still getting the generic error though. Ill keep searching

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that `mail` function in PHP is disabled on a lot of shared servers.

Comment: try commenting out the mail line and see if it no longer gives the generic server error.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely on a server that has display errors off by default. You should be able to enable them in a script (assuming you can't access the server conf or only want it on for one script) with this at the top of your PHP:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
```

Then it should output your errors.

Comment: unfortunately most server configurations will not give you the parse error line numbers.  `php -l` in command line mode is pretty useful for that sort of thing.

Comment: You know, I've never had shell access to a server that I couldn't display_errors on, so I've never come across that. This is why I dev on a different system...

Comment: Yeah if one runs a windows OS, they can install wamp and add the directory containing php.exe to their path and run the command line mode lint check I was talking about.  +1 for your suggestion of turning display_errors on during development though!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting anything in the log is because the php file that sets the error logging and log file contains syntax errors and therefore can't be parsed, so the error log options are never set. To avoid this, I recommend putting this in the php.ini file or in the .htaccess file if possible. You can see how this is done here: http://perishablepress.com/advanced-php-error-handling-via-htaccess/